# jQuery tabs - choose where content panels are created

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, panels

I'm wondering if it possible to dynamically create the tab panels in a specified location?

At the moment my tabs are dynamically created through loading some json. My div structure is like so:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="tablist"></ul>
</div>
```

It then populates the structure dynamically similar to below...

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="tablist">
   <li><a href="#panel1">blah1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#panel2">blah2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#panel3">blah3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="panel1">Some content...</div>
  <div id="panel2">Some content...</div>
  <div id="panel3">Some content...</div>
</div>
```

I would like to tell jQuery to create the panel divs in a parent div of my choice, Eg '#panels':

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="tablist"></ul>
</div>
<div id="panels"></div>
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

FYI I'm not using the generic ui tab look & feel, so not bound by any container design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it possible to dynamically create the tab panels in a specified location?

Not easily (that I can see).

You could, if you really wanted, get a similar behavior by

- creating a second unordered list,
- altering the styling of your current unordered list so that it's not displayed,
- binding events such that clicking any tab in your new list triggers a 'click' event on the "real" list.

Alternatively, you could go the "other way" and get similar behavior by

- creating a second set of panels,
- altering the styling of the "real" panels so that they're not displayed,
- intercepting the "tabsselect" (and similar events) and triggering the corresponding display change in your new panels.

As a note, the jQuery UI tabs API is currently undergoing a [redesign](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tabs-api-redesign). There's a pre-alpha [milestone](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/05/jquery-ui-1-9-milestone-5-tabs-redesign/) available and they're requested comments. It certainly wouldn't hurt to request this as a feature and see what they say. (If nothing else, they may have a better idea than the above.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Something I neglected to mention was that I needed to have a custom div between the tabs & the panels, but I managed to find a workaround. Cheers though.